# How can I find a SSH connection issue

Tags: intellij-idea, magento, ssh, phpstorm, warden

My OS is Ubuntu 22.

I am using warden for running Magento, and want to connect PhpStorm to my database. The database has been imported correctly and it is fine and I can see the output Magento site, but there is an issue in connecting PhpStorm to my database.

I have search a lot and and it seems that there is a SSH tunnel connection issue (as you know for connecting to database we need to run SSH tunnel) .

After running this command

```
ssh user@tunnel.warden.test
```

I get this error :

```
user@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

I have created SSH keys again but it still does not get connected to the tunnel server.